# Select query on update finds no records

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm missing something here and hope someone can point out my error. The following select statement returns rows as expected.

```
 SELECT sku, releasedate FROM staging_product_dimensions WHERE TO_DAYS(`releasedate`) > TO_DAYS(NOW())-30 ;
```

Yet when I use the same where condition in an update statement no records are found. Any insight into why?

```
 UPDATE staging_product t1 
 JOIN staging_product_dimensions t2 
         ON t1.sku = t2.sku
 SET t1.categories = CONCAT(t1.categories,';;','What\'s New')
 WHERE TO_DAYS(t2.releasedate) > TO_DAYS(NOW())-30 ;
```

Comment: The logical conclusion is that the `join` fails.

Comment: Join works fine...I can do this and get expected results

    SELECT t1.sku, t2.releasedate  FROM staging_product as t1
   JOIN staging_product_dimensions as t2 
             ON t2.sku = t1.sku   
              WHERE TO_DAYS(t2.releasedate) > TO_DAYS(NOW())-30 ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four reasons why you would get no rows from this update:

1. The syntax is invalid or the code is not running or it is not running on the correct database.
2. The `where` clause fails.
3. The `join` fails.
4. The value being set is the same as the original value.

I am discounting (1), because you seem to be able to run a `select` query with the same columns and tables.

If the next two are not the reason, then the fourth would appear to be.  This would only happen if the value were `NULL`.  You might try this `set` clause instead:

```
SET t1.categories = CONCAT(COALESCE(t1.categories, ''), ';;', 'What\'s New')
```

Comment: That was it the values were NULL. Didn't realize it would do that. Thanks